# One database, multiple frontends, maintaing request ordering

Tags: database, architecture

Assuming I have one database keeping a simple history with multiple front ends talking to it (one front end per server), I wonder what are the common solutions to deal with time. As soon as I have multiple servers, I cannot assume a global consistent clock, and I was interested in the possible solutions to maintain some kind of ordering between requests.

For a concrete example, let's say I want to record histories of customers, where history is defined as time ordered set of records. The record table would be as simple as (customer_id, time, data), and history would be all the rows where customer_id == requested id. Each request sent by the user would contain one record sent to one customer. Ideally, the time should refer to the "actual" time the request was sent to the front end by the customer (as that's the time as seen from the user POV). To be exact, I only care about preserving the ordering between records for each customer, not about the absolute time.

I am aware of solutions such as vector clocks, etc... but that seems rather complex, and I would expect this to be a rather common issue ?

Solutions which are not acceptable in my case:

- Changing the requests arriving at the front end: I unfortunately have to work under the constraint that the requests are passed as is. I have complete control of whatever communication protocol is needed between front ends and database, though.
- Server time clocks are synchronized
- All request which require being ordered to each other are handled by the same front end server

[EDIT]: the question may sound a bit like red-herring, so here is my rationale for asking it: while this is not my issue right now, I am interested in the possibility to go to a platform like Google App Engine, which explicitly says that their servers are not guaranteed to be time synchronized. The solution to that issue for request ordering does not sound obvious to me - but maybe something like vector clock is actually the only "good" solution ?

Comment: Any issue with generating time on database server using now() function

Comment: Maybe my explanation was not clear, but this cannot work, because I want to maintain the ordering as seen on the front ends, which can be different from the order they arrive at the database. (h1 arrives on Front End 1, h2 arrives later on Front End 2, but the Front End 2 update the database for h2 before Front End 1 does for h1).

Answer (score 0):

> As soon as I have multiple servers, I
>   cannot assume a global consistent
>   clock

Well, you can configure servers to sync their clocks to a time server. You could also configure your database server to sync to a time server, and configure the other servers to sync to your database server as often as you need to. (I'm not saying that's a great idea, just saying it's possible. If you have access to all the servers.)

Anyway . . . so the front ends are the only pieces of software you have that actually know when a request arrives. Is that right?

If that's right, then it's the front ends job to record the time of the customer's request, possibly in UTC, and then forward that timestamp to the database.

If you can't synchronize the server's clocks, then I think your only hope is to have every front ends ask just one specific server--maybe your database server, but maybe not--what time it is when a customer request arrives. A front end can do that by asking for daytime on port 13 (DAYTIME protocol, RFC-867), asking for time on port 37 (TIME protocol, RFC-868), or asking a time server on port 123 (either NTP or SNTP protocol, RFC-1305 and RFC-2030).

But after reading your edit, I think what you want is impossible. You seem to be saying that

- what the front ends send doesn't
  contain enough information to
  reconstruct the "true" ordering
- what the front ends send cannot be
  changed

If the front ends can't send you any other information, vector clocks and interval tree clocks won't help.

Comment: Assuming the clock cannot be set consistantly (if it could, then problem solved), each front end has a different clock, so just recording the UTC does not guarantee that I can rebuild the ordering as seen by the person sending the requests (see my comment to Zimbabao).

Comment: If front ends cannot communicate additional information to each other and to the database, then obviously nothing can be done. I cannot modify what the front end receives from outside world, but I can modify what they themselves send (i.e. I am in a situation where vector clock should definitely solve the problem).

Comment: Won't each front end need to receive and update vector clocks from the other front ends? If they can do that, why can't they also do the admittedly simpler query of a common server for a timestamp?

Comment: While the issue may be mostly theoretical, I think that you still have an issue with a common server to synchronize time because of the latency involved with server communication. There is also the issue of dealing with redundancy when the common server fails. For those reasons, it sounds to me a bit equivalent to allowing for servers to be synchronized

Comment: If the point is to avoid vector clocks, I think you're stuck with real clocks. "NTP provides accuracies generally in the range of 0.1 ms with fast LANs and computers and up to a few tens of milliseconds in the intercontinental Internet." Use the database server to sync time; you can't do anything if it fails anyway.

Answer (score 0):

When you perform any action that records history data to the database you could record two sets of datetime info:

- the datetime as set by the DB when the record was inserted
- the datetime passed through with the data as a legitimate piece of metadata.

The former would give you a central view of the world if you ever needed it, and the latter would let you reconstruct datetime from customers perspective.

If you were ultra-keen you could also pass through the datetime from the users browser by filling some sort of parameter/field using JavaScript.

Comment: This is a legitimate solution, but I forgot to mention that I do not control in any way the requests sent to me, so I cannot add information in the request itself.

Comment: Then the question becomes "what can you control"?  Maintaining a view of the order process on the web server is it's responsibility - so if it doesn'tt currently do that then it sounds like the design needs to change.  My question to you now is - are you are after a "proper" long-term strategic solution or a short-term tactical hack?

Comment: The issue is that I have *multiple* web servers, and I need to maintain the order *between* those servers. Order within one single server is a non issue. I am interested in both workable and long term solutions - I need to a solution soon, but would also like to know my options when I will have the option to redesign things (which I don't have at the moment).

Comment: As for what I control: I can do almost anything as far as communication goes between front end servers, and between front end servers and the database backend.